# React (Next.js) performance tips (using scroll handler for UI state change high-up in app)

Tags: performance, reactjs, optimization, scroll, next.js

I am working on a complicated project that involves disabling in-browser scrolling and simulating scroll via a component that has a bunch of logic for calculations based on wheel/touchmove deltaX updates (highlighted in react-dev-tools image below). Most significantly, it passes this data to react-motion, manipulating the transform3d css of a 'scroll-tray' element that wraps `{ this.props.children }`. But also it's connected to redux and passes a lot of data to be used around the app.

[image]

In addition to the css transform on the 'scroll-tray' wrapper, the 'ScrollOMatic' component's background-color is updated on every increment from the scroll-data-reducer and the component is re-rendered. Very expensive.

Is there a more performant way to handle all this?

The only thing I can think of is to somehow pass down a component, in the 'background', to change color, instead of literally wrapping `{ this.props.children }` with something changing. But would this actually help? to have a separate div underneath that takes the background-color rendering off the higher component's hands? Like so:

[image]
But the ScrollOMatic would still re-render, down the tree to the entire app, because of the css transform, yeah? And I don't see a way around this, since the whole point is that it is literally moving the entire nested content of the app as if the page was being scrolled.

Any thoughts would be super appreciated! Not much experience with React optimization, especially not with something this high in the tree and rapidly updated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question I think you problem is that you have a wrapper component wich render on the scroll of the mouse and this make that all the child do a render. Your problem is with the render as you specified:

> In addition to the css transform on the 'scroll-tray' wrapper, the 'ScrollOMatic' component's background-color is updated on every increment from the scroll-data-reducer and the component is re-rendered. Very expensive.

In the link of [optimizing-performance](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html) read it all, the section shouldComponentUpdate In Action will help you. Also this link will be good [when-to-rerender](http://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/)

> Other things Your first inclination may be to use refs to “make things happen” in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more critically about where state should be owned in the component hierarchy. Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to “own” that state is at a higher level in the hierarchy. See the Lifting State Up guide for examples of this.

Try no to use ref attribute [refs-and-the-dom](http://[]%20https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of troubleshooting and some empirical testing with help from a couple devs on a react slack channel, learned that `{ this.props.children }` will NOT re-render automatically in this scenario. Woo!

If a component is passed as an explicit direct child of an updating component and is passed changing props, `shouldComponentUpdate()` inside the child is the appropriate solution.

Because of the structure of this app, there is actually not an effect on the rendering of deeper-nested components.

```
<ParentComponent>
    <ChildComponent someProps={this.state.whatever} /> // will re-render (at least if passed dynamic props)
</ParentComponent>
```

It's not equal to:

```
<ParentComponent>
    { this.props.children } // will not re-render (in this use case props passed via react-redux connected component )
</ParentComponent>
```